# How store iOS audio recordings on Parse?

Tags: ios, audio, parse-platform, recording

Newbie iOS coder here, apologies if the answer is really simple.

So I set up my audio recording in viewDidLoad

```
// Set the audio file
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

I have a bar button that records new audio files:

```
 // Stop the audio player before recording
if (player.playing) {
    [player stop];
}

if (!recorder.recording) {
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Start recording
    [recorder record];

} else {

    // Pause recording
    [recorder pause];
}

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Stop" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(stopTapped)];
```

Then the start becomes a stop button

```
[recorder stop];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(actionNew)];
```

How can I add this as a PFFile and save in a dictionary in Parse?
I've read through a lot of the Parse documentation but still don't really get the hang of it. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simplest solution is to load the file from the phone when the user is finished recording instead of trying to save the recording directly to an `NSData` object. If you want to look into recording straight to an `NSData` object check out [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485032/record-audio-to-nsdata).

First you want to get an instance of `NSData` after the user has finished recording :

```
NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Make a new PFFile :

```
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"resume.txt" data:data];
```

And then save it with your desired saving method.